# How to Replace a PHP File With an Existing PHP File

Tags: php

So currently I have two PHP files, they are identical. There is a function that updates the current file being used to add data and also a clear function. I want the clear function on the first file to replace itself with the content of the second.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want as currently it just sounds like you should re-use some of the functions rather than replace them.

Comment: @NigelRen I think he's modifying the script dynamically, and wants to reset it back to the original version.

Comment: @Barmar, think I was trying to get at the idea of why someone is modifying code dynamically rather than a data driven design.  Unless there is some very complex coding needed it is easy to mess this up and it doesn't work down the line.

Comment: @NigelRen It sounded like you were asking about the reset function, not updating the file in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__FILE__` to get the pathname of the current file, and overwrite this with the second file.

```
copy("/path/to/second/file.php", __FILE__);
```

Comment: so this is just a function that php already has integrated?

Comment: The ability to copy files? Yes, it has had it for many years.